# .htaccess Redirect from a folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm working on a task where I need to redirect all traffic going to a particular folder back to the root:

```
Redirect /ridestream_start/ /index.php
#effectively, ridestream_start was our beta folder, 
#and we're moving our functionality to the root folder
```

It wouldn't be very efficient to code a redirect for every single file and folder inside of 'ridestream_start' as there are tons of them…how would I accomplish coding a redirect using only the folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/ridestream_start/.* /index.php.com[L,R=301]
```

Comment: Beautiful…this link builds on that: http://bit.ly/lLTZMZ (found a solution about 3 seconds after posting)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, I think the following will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ridestream_start/ /index.php
```